# C++ Linker Trouble, Unresolved External Symbol with my own code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I've been having a rather frustrating linker issue that doesn't make much sense to me.  I have the 4 following files:

```
// CompileFunctions.h
#pragma once
#include "FileListing.h"
int compileSheet(FileListing & file);
int compileVerse(FileListing & file);

// CompileSheet.cpp
#include "CompileFunctions.h"
int compileSheet(FileListing & file){
    ...
}

// CompileVerse.cpp
#include "CompileFunctions.h"
int compileVerse(FileListing & file){
    ...
}

// main.cpp
#include "CompileFunctions.h"
int main(){
    ...
    compileSheet(file);
    compileVerse(file);
}
```

This generates the following linker error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl compileVerse(struct FileListing &)" (?compileVerse@@AAUFileListing@@@Z)
```

I've tried adding `extern` to the declarations in the header, checked to make sure both source files were in the same directory and compiling, and cleaned the build.  But nothing seems to help.  Given how an identical function is linking fine while the other is not is baffling me, I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: So does your project build successfully if you remove the call to `compileVerse(file);`?

Comment: @MohamadElghawi - It does, oddly...

Comment: It could be some rogue `extern "C"` that changes the function signature between declaration and definition. `extern "C"` functions are, like, totally different than those that are not `extern "C"`.

Comment: Nothing odd about it. The linker is complaining about that symbol in particular so by not referencing it you shut the linker up. I agree with  Dialecticus. Either way I'm sure that your issue is in parts of your code that you have not posted.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi - you were right, though it was actually a rogue setting in the IDE in this case.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I was just about to say make sure that CompileVerse.obj is actually being generated.

Answer (score 1):

[image: picture of config menu]

Following one of the comments, it seemed like `VerseCompiler.cpp` was acting weird.  I checked it's property page to see if it was being excluded from the build and found another culprit:

Despite the file's name, it was being treated as a header file by Visual Studio.  I'm guessing I must've mistakenly created it as a .cpp file and renamed it without realizing this didn't change it's behaviour.  Setting this to `C/C++ Compiler` fixed my linker issue.